# Flutter Card Shape

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was building my own cards using the flutter gallery as an example, however when setting shape it says the parameter shape is not defined. I am not sure how this is possible since I was under the impression shape was a default property of the Card class? I am new to flutter sorry if this is a super simple fix. I have been messing with it for a couple days now.

```
final ShapeBorder shape;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new SafeArea(
    top: false,
    bottom: false,
    child: new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      height: height,
      child: new Card(
        elevation: 8.0,
        color: const Color(0xFFf0e7d1),
        shape: shape,  // The first shape is not defined, second is fine?
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new SizedBox(
              height: 154.0,
              child: new Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Positioned.fill(
                      child: new Image.asset(
                        destination.assetName,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                  ),
                  new Positioned(
                    bottom: 16.0,
                    left: 16.0,
                    right: 16.0,
                    child: new FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: new Text(
                          destination.title
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out you do not actually need a size implementation there at all so i just removed it and all good!